# Pipe in space outputs gas - what is its angular momentum at $t$ and $t+dt$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

Given a pipe in space (neglect gravitational force):
[image]

- The speed of the gas is $v_0$ (in relative to the edge of the pipe)
- The length of the pipe is $l$
- The pipe rests (not moving) at $t=0$
- The gas spreads equally along the pipe

What would be the angular momentum at $t$ and at $(t+dt)$ during the process of outputting $(-dm)$ mass from the pipe?

I've tried using the definition: $L = \Sigma m_ir_i\times v_i$.
But at $t$ it is zero (which doesn't make sense): $L(t) = m \cdot 0 \times V_{cm}$. I calculated it in relative to the centre of mass of the pipe (i.e. $r_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}l$), therefore $r=0$.

What am I missing here?

---

### Edit #1:

At time $t$ it is **before** the mass leaves the pipe.
At time $(t+dt)$ it is **after** that the mass left the pipe.

Comment: Why doesn't L=0 at t=0 make sense? Remember that it is a vector and you can have two contributions that cancel.

Comment: I maybe don't understand the figure. If the gas leaves the pipe through the opening that you show, the opening is at a distance $l/2$ from the center-of-mass of the pipe. Then $\vec r = \vec l/2$ and it is perpendicular to $v_0$.

Comment: @Eoin: L is zero at $t=0$. But at some time $t$ it can't be zero..

Comment: @Sofia: Indeed but at time $t$ it is **before** the mass leaves the pipe. At time $t+dt$ it is after that the mass left the pipe. Sorry for not specifying that, I thought it was a convention.

Comment: @Dor, yes it can. You sum up the contribution from the mas exiting the tube and the tube itself. Depending on your choice of axes, one is negative and one is positive

Comment: @Eoin: If I choose to calculate the angular momentum from the center of mass of the tube? Then it is zero as I showed in my first post. Or probably not.. but I don't know where I'm mistaken.

Comment: A tube rotating about its centre of mass does not have zero angular momentum. Both the sign of $r_i$ and $v_i$ change between the 'top' and 'half' of your image

Answer (score 1):

After the mass exits the pipe, the tube will start to rotate from the recoil.

At $t=0$, there is zero angular momentum, $L=0$.

Let's take it that the pipe rotates about its centre-of-mass, and use that point as the origin from which to calculate the angular momentum.

At time $t+dt$, the puff of gas has angular momentum $L_{gas} = dm \times l/2 \times v0$.

So, through conservation of angular momentum, the pipe must have $L_{pipe}=-L_{gas}$.

The angular momentum of the pipe is from the relation

$L = \frac{m_{pipe}}{l}\int_{-l/2}^{l/2}  r_i  v_i dr_i$.

Since the pipe is a rigid body, $v_i = r_i \omega$,

$L = \frac{m_{pipe}}{l}\int_{-l/2}^{l/2} r_i^2 \omega dr_i $

$ = \frac{m_{pipe}}{l} \frac{1}{3} \omega r_i^3 |_{-l/2}^{l/2} $

$ = \frac{1}{12} m_{pipe} l^2 \omega$

At this point you might recognise the moment of inertia of a straight rod about its centre,

$I=\frac{1}{12} m l^2$, which would have been the other way to approach this.

Now all you have to do is equate the two expressions for the angular momentum to find the rotation rate

Comment: (1) You showed the angular momentum at $t=0$ and at $t+dt$. What happens in $t$? (before the gas leaves the pipe). (2) Why did you divided the equation of the angular momentum with the length of the pipe $(l)$ ? Is it due to the additional $dr_i$?

Comment: (1) this depends on a lot of things, but to a first approximation, since I don't see that the gas imparts a force on the pipe
(2) the quantity $\frac{m}{l} dr$ is the mass of an infinitesimal length of the pipe

Comment: (1) It seems that the sentence that you wrote is incomplete (??)

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Then I don't understand the sentence. You wrote "**since** I don't see that the gas imparts a force on the pipe". When writing "Since that X", the expression ", then Y" comes after it. But in your sentence there's only the first part - "Since X". Could you please write the same sentence in a different manner? Thanks :)

Comment: To a first approximation, nothing happens because the gas doesn't impart a (net) force on the pipe?

Comment: @Dor, oh, I'm sorry, I just saw what the problem was -- yes, I messed up the first (1) sentence. Sorry.